# Control to render a flow chart

Tags: html, css, asp.net, radiobuttonlist, flowchart

This might be a very silly question but here goes nothing: is there any asp net control, ajax control toolkit or html/css tag to create something like a radiobuttonlist, horizontally aligned with all radiobuttons connected by a line or dotted line? I would have uploaded a picture but I lost all my reputation on a previous bounty and it seems I have to have at least 10 rep to upload an image.

Basically, I have a web form in which the user inputs some data and then that data has 4 steps: draft, completed, sent to approval, approved. I would like to have these 4 steps at the top of the page and based on the current status, check the appropriate status on that ribbon.

UPDATE:

A picture's worth a 1000 words so therefore this is what I need:

[image]

And also this control should be "controlled" in the code-behind.

Comment: Try to insert relevant code into your question. That would help a lot!

Comment: @Error404: Have you read the question? What code should I enter when I am just asking if there is an out of the box control (asp, ajax, html) that can help me in this situation? I've updated the question with a picture as to what I need. I finally got the minimum rep required to do that ... but not thanks to whoever down rated my question :)

Comment: That was what I meant. Any related code or graphics.

Comment: @Error404: Ok, update the question with a picture of what I would need to achieve. Any suggestions please?

Comment: You could write a custom server control, have the images as a resource in the assembly, and display the appropriate image. For example, to achieve 4 steps, you would need 4 images (one for each step). One that shows Step 1 only, then another one to cover from step 1 to step 2, another to cover from step 2 to step 3, and yet another to cover from step 3 to step 4. Alternatively you can use the HTML 5 canvas. I can't think of any components or libraries that do this for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily make this with html/css.

```
<div class="bubble active"></div>
<div class="connector"></div>
<div class="bubble"></div>
<div class="connector"></div>
<div class="bubble"></div>
<div class="connector"></div>
<div class="bubble"></div>
```

And some basic css

```
 .bubble
{
border-radius:50%;
height:40px;
width:40px;
background: #aaa;
display:inline-block;
margin:0 -3px;
}

.bubble.active
{
background:red;
}

.connector
{
display:inline-block;
height:3px;
width:10%;
background: #aaa;
vertical-align:middle;
margin-top:-30px;
}
```

Check out this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fxbwyfth/). Just add/remove the active class to the bubbles at will. And you can also add a done class or something.

Comment: You're a genius! :) Simple and nice!